# concatenate two fields in different tables with mysql?

Tags: mysql

It can be concatenate fields in a table.

But I want to know if you can concatenate two fields where "a" is in categories table and the "other" is in the products table, bone in different tables with mysql.

Comment: Can you provide an example of data, and the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
SELECT CONCAT(tableOne.stringOne, tableTwo.stringTwo) 
  FROM tableOne, tableTwo WHERE tableOne.joinField = tableTwo.joinField;
```